# Keras LSTM, is the time_step equal to 1 like transforming the LSTM into a MLP?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm a beginer in this field of Deep Learning. I'm trying to use **Keras** for a *LSTM* in a regression problem. I would like to build an *ANN* which could exploit the memory cell between one prediction and the next one.

In more details... I have a neural network (**Keras**) with *2 Hidden layer-LSTM* and 1 output layer for a regression context.

The `batch_size` is equal to 7, `timestep` equal to 1 and I have **5749 samples**. 
I'm only interested to understand if using `timestep == 1` is the same thing as using an *MLP* instead of *LSTM*. For `time_step`, I'm referring to the reshape phase for the input of the *Sequential* model in **Keras**. The output is a single regression.

I'm not interested in the previous inputs, but I'm interested only on the output of the network as an information for the next prediction.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can say so :)

You're right in thinking that you won't have any recurrency anymore.
But internally, there will be still more operations than in regular `Dense` layers, due to the existence of more kernels.

But be careful:

- If you use `stateful=True`, it will still be a recurrent LSTM!
- If you use initial states properly, you can still make it recurrent.

If you're interested in creating custom operations with the memory/state of the cells, you could try creating your custom recurrent cell taking the [LSTMCell](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py/#L1689) code as a template.

Then you'd use that cell in a `RNN(CustomCell, ...)` layer.